# install python 3.5.2 into ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I want to change the python version from 3.6 to 3.5. 
I installed python3.5 on ubuntu 16.04. but it is not in usr/bin
I executed `update-alternatives --display python3`

```
    python3 - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/python3.6
  link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.6
  link python3 is /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 3
/usr/local/lib/python3.5 - priority 1
/usr/local/lib/python3.6 - priority 2
```

But I execute `python3 -V`

```
Python 3.5.2
```

When I try to install some packages using pip

```
pip install pymysql


-bash: /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I want to correctly install python 3.5.2 on the computer and set it as the default version.

Comment: try pip3 install?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com) for installing and managing your Python environments. This way you can maintain different versions of Python on your system without the risk of conflicts like the one you're experiencing.

Comment: I tried `pip3 install` but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

1) Install pre-requiste

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall

sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

2) Move to src folder and get the tar of python3.5.2

```
cd /usr/src

sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz
```

3) Now extract the downloaded archive on your system.

```
sudo tar xzf Python-3.5.2.tgz
```

4) Compile the source using alInstall

```
cd Python-3.5.2

sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations

sudo make altinstall
```

5) Check the install

```
python3.5 -V
```